# Unable to edit my comments on Android app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

When I try to hit the arrow in the lower right corner of my comments I am unable to edit my comments. Instead the side bar pops up a little bit. I am using a Samsung Tab 7 inch.

Comment: Is the bar at the top showing up when you tap on the comment?

Comment: @StevenV Yes, with four icons: Done, Reply, Person and Menu. Menu only shows Copy Text.

Comment: Positive it isn't outside the editing period? "Edit" is in the menu for me. Try it with your comment above (if you see this in the next 4 minutes or so). Could be tablet related since "View profile" is also in the menu?

Comment: Testing an edit from android here... I seem to be able to edit. It's in the menu after selecting the comment.

Comment: @StevenV okay, there's the edit icon. Looks like UX tweak might be in order.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's within the 5 minute window for an edit, you should be able to see an icon with a pencil when tapping on a comment, if you long-click on the icon it will say "Edit".